# Keeping a long term base in DayZ

Tags: dayz-2012

I have acquired a black SUV and been able to keep it for several days now. My current gear include a pile of weapons (DMR, multiple AK's, Bison, MP5SD, pistols etc), plenty of food, a tent and lots of other stuff. I've been keeping everything in my car, and I've found a very good place to park it when I log off. I'm playing on a semi-busy server with peak daily player count at around 20-30.

I haven't really been able to keep a base in DayZ for very long before. Mostly my tents have been looted within 2-3 days, and I've lost all my vehicles pretty quickly up til now.

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some advice on how to keep and maintain a base over longer periods of time. I know location is important. But how about routine server restarts? Are tents safer than cars? How about enter/exit routes to and from the base? Perhaps splitting a base into several smaller bases?

Any advice will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I always thought the end goal of DayZ was to establish a base somewhere to operate more freely out of. Recently I've realized that this isn't the point of the game at all, and that "horders" (players who accumulate lots of gear in a car/tent) is often critized for playing this way. More seasoned players will often destroy bases they find without even looting them first.

Comment: Try to avoid common locations for bases, such as the Dams, or in the forest that lies along the northern edge of the map.

Comment: @Domocus Indeed. I know some high level players sometimes do helicopter runs in search of bases up there.

Answer (score 1):

As many players specifically watch for bases/hidden caches etc, the only real technique to protect your stash is to work in a small group of individuals to have continuous activity on the server.

Of course, you'd need to trust your little clan...which is perhaps a separate issue :-)

Comment: Alas, none of my friends are very active in this game. And as you say, I wouldn't trust anyone I didn't know. So I guess I'm doomed for a lone wolf play style. But of course, working in a group would have many advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Two Answers:

1. Some people consider this hacking, and I personally don't do it, but putting a vehicle in a somehow bugged spot (so it's stuck in a wall) makes it impossible for helicopter teams or snipers to find it.
2. If it's against your ethics of the game, or you simply can't find a buggy area, the best solution is not to have a permanent base. Go sort of "nomad" style, and hide it in a forest every time you log off. Simply go where the loot is, and move it at least once a day. If you won't be able to log on for a while, put it in the southeast. loot hunters never seem to look there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty awesome permanent base in Skalisky island in a house. Make sure if you want a permanent base, get a helicopter and take it to a far off island and go to a very sparsely populated area. Go to a barn and put buses on the doors and make sure you put barb wire around the bus.

What you will need

1. about 30 bear traps
2. a tool box
3. barb wire
4. 2 city buses
5. 1 heli (OPTIONAL)
6. Tents
7. A gun and ammo for protection while building

Or this, I went to a building on the north east side of the map and I put bear traps along the tree line and the main exits. Leave about 20 feet of space between each of the bear traps and put barb wire around these bear traps. With the 20 feet of space put a bus for a gate. Also, put a car by a 2nd floor window for a alternate exit/entry and put tents on each of the floors to separate your valuables. Have a person guard you while building. This is my base currently on the Canadian server and if you want put a heli (OPTIONAL).